# Apache Virtual host response with a wrong page

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I am a newbie and try to host a website using Apache2 on Ubuntu 19.10.

#### Main site - /var/www/main/index.html

apache.conf

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
<Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

ports.conf

```
Listen 80 
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
  
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

main.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/www.main.com.key
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/www.main.com.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local     /ssl/www.main.com.intermediate.crt
    LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/error_log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Up to this point - everything works as it should.

- type url - https://www.main.com (works fine)
- type url - http://www.main.com (works fine - redirect it to https)

#### Subdomain site - /var/www/sub/index.html

sub.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub
    ServerName sub.main.com
    LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/error_sub_log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</virtualHost>
```

Here is the main problem.

- type url - https://www.main.com (works fine)
- type url - http://www.main.com (works fine)
- type url - http://sub.main.com (works fine)
- type url - http://abc.main.com (works fine???)

Why is fine (abc.main.com)? My browser displays the content as same as sub.main.com. It seems that I can enter anything e.g. xyz.main.com and I still get the content of sub.main.com. What do I need to do in order to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since abc.main.com doesn't exist; therefore, the sub.main.com html page becomes a default page.